# Angular2 - Http Services - How do I ensure I have real time data all the time

Tags: rest, http, angular

I am new to Angular2 and I am trying to figure out how to display real time data without refreshing the page. For ex; a list of orders. When I am on orders page and I make a Http service call, I get say 5 records. After I have fetched those records, if 2 new records are added I want to be able to see them at the top of the page without refreshing the page? How do I do that?

I read about using Observable/subscribe but I am confused. Once it gives me 5 records, I am assuming it won't give me the latest 2 records unless I use Observable.interval right? Which means every few seconds it will make the http request call again and receive the latest data??

Comment: To get a new data you need some kind of data transfer to happen anyway.  It's not Angular specific. You can poll your data based on time interval or user activity or you can use duplex connections like websocket or something else. There are already some packages for working with websocket in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

You can either refetch your data every now and then, which isn't efficient, but will get the job done with little setup. If you want "real real-time" data, you need some kind of pushing mechanism. Common ones are `HTTP long-polling` and `websockets`.

Off the top of my head these come to mind (all node-based, I don't know what your server-side looks like):

tools to help your with a real-time API

- Meteor
- sails.js
- feathersjs

some transport helpers:

- socket.io
- sockJS
- primus